# Django ImageField: how to make upload_to parameter dependent on self.id?

Tags: django, django-models

Supose there is a site with 1 million users, and they all have at least one profile image (maybe more).

I'm not sure, but I think that storing all that images in one folder is not very smart (in terms of speed, because there need some time to find one image between a million and more images in that folder need more time to find anything there).

So, as a variant we can store that images in different folders (even if few levels of nested folders).

For example: users with id 1-1000 will store their images in folder 1; users with id 1001-2000 will store their images in folder 2 and so on...

To do this we need `upload_to` parameter of ImageField must be dynamic (dependent on user id or in other words `self.id`).

Are there any ways to make it dynamic?
Or maybe there are some more proper ways of implementing this scenario?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function as the upload_to parameter... in your case:

```
def upload_to_by_id(instance, filename):
    if instance.id:
        # you already have an id (updating a model with a new file)
        folder = str(self.id/1000 +1)
    else:
        # maybe you still don't have an id!! this can happen a lot... :/
        folder = 'tmp'

    return '%s/%s' % (folder, filename)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where do I put this function? Is it under the model class or is it separate to the model class?