# global upload_to overriding in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say i have many models like that:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

class AnotherExampleClass(models.Model):
    another_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='another_images/')
```

So, it's many different models with ImageFields, which have different field names. What i want, is to somehow override all `upload_to` like that:

```
upload_to = '%s/%s' % (upload_to, self.id)
```

for instance, if i upload picture to `another_image` field, file path would be:

```
'another_images/1/picture.jpg'
```

I realize that i need to create some `CustomImageField` based on `models.ImageField`. But how exactly achive that with minimal pain?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535189/django-imagefield-how-to-make-upload-to-parameter-dependent-on-self-id/8535432 and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`upload_to` [can be](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) a callable. You know what to do next. :-)

Comment: it's possible to get field name inside of callable upload_to?

Comment: @nukl No, it isn't. But yiu can make a factory to return special function for each field.